# Typescript difference between two arrays

Tags: arrays, typescript, difference

Is there a way to return the missing values of list_a from list_b in TypeScrpit?

For example:

```
var a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z'];
```

The result value is

```
['e', 'f', 'g'].
```

Comment: So you would like to compare a1 and a2 and check which is missing in a2 and print them or add them in a2? I'm not sure if I understood it right..

Comment: I need element missing in a1 from a2 but I don't need element missing in a2 from a1.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

There are probably a lot of ways, for example using the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let missing = a1.filter(item => a2.indexOf(item) < 0);
console.log(missing); // ["e", "f", "g"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20a1%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'%2C%20'f'%2C%20'g'%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20a2%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20missing%20%3D%20a1.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20a2.indexOf(item)%20%3C%200)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(missing)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22e%22%2C%20%22f%22%2C%20%22g%22%5D))

---

#### Edit

The `filter` function runs over the elements of `a1` and it reduce it (but in a new array) to elements who are in `a1` (because we're iterating over it's elements) and are missing in `a2`.

Elements in `a2` which are missing in `a1` won't be included in the result array (`missing`) as the filter function doesn't iterate over the `a2` elements:

```
var a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z', 'hey', 'there'];

let missing = a1.filter(item => a2.indexOf(item) < 0);
console.log(missing); // still ["e", "f", "g"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20a1%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'%2C%20'f'%2C%20'g'%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20a2%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'z'%2C%20'hey'%2C%20'there'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20missing%20%3D%20a1.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20a2.indexOf(item)%20%3C%200)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(missing)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22e%22%2C%20%22f%22%2C%20%22g%22%5D))

Comment: it seems good but ii shows also the values that I have in B and I don't have in A. but I don't need them.

Comment: It returns `["e", "f", "g"]` just like you wanted...  So I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I edited my question. If I have a 'z' in a2 your script return also the 'z' but I don't need it

Comment: No, my script will still return `["e", "f", "g"]` even with the added `z` to `a2`. even `var a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z', 'hey', 'there'];` it will still return the requested missing values, [check it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20a1%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'%2C%20'f'%2C%20'g'%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20a2%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'z'%2C%20'hey'%2C%20'there'%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20missing%20%3D%20a1.filter(item%20%3D%3E%20a2.indexOf(item)%20%3C%200)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(missing)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22e%22%2C%20%22f%22%2C%20%22g%22%5D).

Comment: That's perfect, thant you.
I just wrote this little "array diff" function for anyone interested:

const arrayDiffs = (oldArray: any[] = [], newArray: any[] = []) => {
  const added = newArray.filter((item) => oldArray.indexOf(item) < 0);
  const removed = oldArray.filter((item) => newArray.indexOf(item) < 0);
  return { added, removed };
};

Comment: What about performance ? a1.filter(item => a2.indexOf(item) < 0) is just a nested loop in disguise. Isn't there a solution that uses Sets ?

Comment: This handles type well:
arrayDifference<T>(total: T[], toSubtract: T[]): T[] {
    return total.filter(item => toSubtract.indexOf(item) < 0);
  }

Answer (score 19):

Typescript only provides design / compile time help, it doesn't add JavaScript features. So the solution that works in JavaScript will work in Typescript.

Plenty of ways to solve this, my goto choice would be lodash:
https://lodash.com/docs#difference

```
_.difference(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can only use this method. With the larger table first.

```js
const a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
const a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

const difference_a1 = a1.filter(x => !a2.includes(x));

const difference_a2 = a2.filter(x => !a1.includes(x));

console.log(difference_a1);
/* ["e","f","g"] */

 console.log(difference_a2);
/* ["x","y","z"] */
```

Answer (score 4):

You can look for both values:

```js
const removed = before.filter((x: any) => !after.includes(x));
const added = after.filter((x: any) => !before.includes(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't leverage the power of Javascript :-)

```
var a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k', 'l', 'M', 'j'];
let difference: string[] = [];
difference = difference.concat(a1.filter(item => a2.indexOf(item) < 0))
.concat(a2.filter(item => a1.indexOf(item) < 0));

or 

difference = difference.concat(a1.filter(item => !a2.include(item)))
.concat(a2.filter(item => !a1.include(item)));


console.log(difference); // ["e", "f", "g", "k", "l", "M", "j"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
const a2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
     
let bigArray = null;
let smallArray = null;
if(a1.length >= a2.length)
  {
    bigArray = a1;
    smallArray =a2;
  } else {
    bigArray= a2;
    smallArray =a1;
  }       
const diff = bigArray.filter(item => smallArray.indexOf(item) < 0); 
console.log(diff);
```